# SSIS C# Script Component: Writing to Package Variable remains empty

Tags: ssis

I'm reading 2 dates from an Excel file and trying to pass these to Package Variables for use elsewhere in my package.
Below code shows where I execute the Input0_ProcessInputRow to read the 2 date values, and then store them in local variables within the script. (vPeriodStart and vPeriodEnd)

In the PostExecute I then try to set my PackageVariables to the local variables - this does not succeed.
The debugging MessageBoxes show the successful reading of the rows from my Input, but then in PostExecute the MessageBoxes show the values are effectively NULL/empty (01/01/0001)

As a C#-newbie I'm quite sure I've not understood the correct functions/placements to use. Appreciate any guidance in this regard.

[image: C# Code (Script Component)]

[image: Debugging Messages]

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
#endregion


[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
DateTime vPeriodStart;
DateTime vPeriodEnd;

public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();
}

public override void PostExecute()
{
    base.PostExecute();
    
    MessageBox.Show("3 vPeriodStart: " + vPeriodStart.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show("4 vPeriodEnd: " + vPeriodEnd.ToString());

    Variables.HarveyNormanAUPeriodStart = vPeriodStart;
    Variables.HarveyNormanAUPeriodEnd = vPeriodEnd;
}

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    DateTime vPeriodStart = DateTime.Parse(Row.PeriodStart);
    DateTime vPeriodEnd = DateTime.Parse(Row.PeriodEnd);

    MessageBox.Show("1 vPeriodStart: " + vPeriodStart.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show("2 vPeriodEnd: " + vPeriodEnd.ToString());

}

}
```

Comment: Check out here:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22194.use-ssis-variables-and-parameters-in-a-script-task.aspx
 I usually set variables in the SSIS from script task like this:   Dts.Variables["User::MyIntegerVariable"].Value = SomeVariableOrValue

Comment: Thanks @Brad, but I there appear to be some subtle differences as I'm having to use a Script Component within a Data Flow Task. I'm having trouble referencing the "Dts" component and a few other syntactical issues. I'll however use this as guide and see what I similarities I can get done within the Script Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer:
I was re-declaring my variables within the Input0_ProcessInputRow, and even though I have only 1 record in my Input, it seems it ran at least twice and then overwrote my variables.

Detail of how I derived this:
In continuing my troubleshooting, I noticed that the debugging actually completes (green tick) before the MessageBoxes 3 & 4 in the PostExecute section are triggered.
[image]

Even though I was only returning 1 row from my Input
[image]

This got me to thinking that the  reason for the NULL/Empty value in my variable is because the script has seemingly completed and cleared the local variables (vPeriodStart, vPeriodEnd) before it gets to the PostExecute section.

This then got me wondering how is it that the variables vPeriodStart and vPeriodEnd are being cleared - it's almost as if they were being "redefined"... Looking at my code, I am guessing that the second DateTime declaration I have for the 2 variables, is actually overwriting the initial values that were correctly written to them.
(This thinking was inspired by @Mark - even though I truly have only 1 record as Input and the isFirstRow validation had no effect, somehow I naïvely presume that the Input0_ProcessInputRow section has like an EndOfFile reference and it ran through a second time which then re-declared my variables before it exited to the PostExecute section)

By simply removing the 2nd declaration within the Input0_ProcessInputRow section, everything now works and the variable values are preserved long enough to get to the PostExecute section, where my Package variables are then being successfully updated.

[image]

Comment: right, I also noticed this when I first saw your query. Glad, you found it yourself.

Comment: I didn't catch that - nice one!

Answer (score 1):

Brad's note above is correct as far as setting the variable.

Apart from that, if you encountered a null in C#, you would get a null object reference error when trying to set a non-nullable variable. Input0_ProcessInputRow is called for each row, so in the current code, the date variables are getting called for every row.  My guess is that the last row has some weird date like 1/1/0000, so the variables are being set a couple of times.  I ran your code with a single row of data and it worked like you'd expect.

Could you try something like this, adding a variable so you only set the date once:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
#endregion


[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
DateTime vPeriodStart;
DateTime vPeriodEnd;
bool isFirstRow = true;

public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();
}

public override void PostExecute()
{
    base.PostExecute();
    
    MessageBox.Show("3 vPeriodStart: " + vPeriodStart.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show("4 vPeriodEnd: " + vPeriodEnd.ToString());

    Variables.HarveyNormanAUPeriodStart = vPeriodStart;
    Variables.HarveyNormanAUPeriodEnd = vPeriodEnd;
}

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    if(isFirstRow)
    {
    DateTime vPeriodStart = DateTime.Parse(Row.PeriodStart);
    DateTime vPeriodEnd = DateTime.Parse(Row.PeriodEnd);

    MessageBox.Show("1 vPeriodStart: " + vPeriodStart.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show("2 vPeriodEnd: " + vPeriodEnd.ToString());
    isFirstRow = false;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark. Introducing the isFirstRow validation unfortunately had no effect, and I'm intrigued to know that it worked for you - as per my reference to Brad, is it perhaps because I am using a Script Component in a Data Flow Task?
Anyways, I've managed to solve my problem, but this comments section is too short to type it up. Will post in separate reply.